# Multilevel Login in php&mysqli with codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

i have 3 user with different access page, i have try create login form standart with no limit access. now i'm confussed where i must place new code multiple login. 
( i use php&mysqli database with codeigniter framework )

Please help me,
thk u before

[database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qEYQ.jpg)

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HmTe.jpg)

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('m_rental');
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('login');
    }

    function login(){
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required');
        if($this->form_validation->run() != false){
            $where = array(
                'admin_username' => $username,
                'admin_password' => $password,      
            );
            $data = $this->m_rental->edit_data($where,'admin');
            $d = $this->m_rental->edit_data($where,'admin')->row();
            $cek = $data->num_rows();
            if($cek > 0){
                $session = array(
                    'id'=> $d->admin_id,
                    'nama'=> $d->admin_nama,
                    'status' => 'login'
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($session);
                redirect(base_url().'admin');
            }else{
                redirect(base_url().'welcome?pesan=gagal');         
            }
        }else{
            $this->load->view('login');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add level to your session and read it later on dashboard page:

```
        $session = array(
            'id'=> $d->admin_id,
            'nama'=> $d->admin_nama,
            'status' => 'login',
            'level' => $d->level
        );
```

And on dashboard page

```
if($this->session->userdata["level"] === "superadmin")
{
   // Code if level = superadmin
}
```

Comment: i have try to include what you suggest, but i found error in my program like this...

An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: ParseError

Message: syntax error, unexpected ''level'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')'

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\selawe\application\controllers\Welcome.php

Line Number: 35

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\selawe\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: dont forget to add `comma` after `status => login`

Comment: thks, i can access login page now... but i stil found something error in syntax...
i have 3 page each user can access by level, may you help me where error ?

[my screenshot](https://ibb.co/x62FD2Z)

Comment: thks, i can access login page now... but i stil found something error in syntax... i have 3 page each user can access by level, may you help me where error ? [my screenshot](https://ibb.co/x62FD2Z)

Comment: Add this `if($this->session->userdata["level"] === "superadmin"){` to line 38

Comment: fantastic !!! thanks a lot for you ... :)
this is my final code,success

[my final code](https://ibb.co/pnZzTnR)